# Can I Run Two Full Backups on SQL Server 2005 at the Same Time?

Tags: sql-server-2005, backup, smo

Running SQL Server Express 2005 here.  We are creating several programs which run a backup on the database using Server Management Objects (SMO) mostly through C# (.NET).  We have separate processes that will invoke the backup at different times.

Are there any issues with running two full backups at the same time if they are dumping the backup to different locations?  The processes are pretty independent of each other and it would be a bit of work to synchronize them all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Shouldn't be an issue, assuming your I/O subsystem can keep up. ("Different locations" may mean different things to different people - it's not just about drive letters.)

Comment: Aaron is correct you can two full backup running at a time. However, you can't have two simultaneous log backups... one will wait other to complete.

Comment: +1 Just to supplement your answer, Aaron, a good resource is here on TechNet: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189315(v=sql.90).aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Also, starting with SQL Server 2005, it's possible to create concurrent log and full/differential backups

Just note that the inactive part of the log file in not cleared immedeatly after the log backup is completed, but after the full/differential backup is completed

Check out this Paul Randal's post: [Search Engine Q&A #16: Concurrent log and full backups](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/post/search-engine-qa-16-concurrent-log-and-full-backups.aspx)